# How to check that an image comes from the devices camera HTML5

Tags: javascript, php, html

I'm having an issue which could be an edge case.
The thing is that I'm developing a web site that is acting as a mobile app (something like a mobile first website) and to do this, I found a method to open the camera of the device when the user click on a file input.

Until there every works fine. The problem is that when I open the website on my laptop, when I click the input file, it opens a file selector, instead of open the camera of the device.
Also when I click the input file on some mobile devices, sometimes happens some of the following: 1. select photo from the gallery 2. open the camera
Which aren't accepted in my project, due to it only can accept recent photos(which are taken at that moment).

Anybody knows how to control this?
Really thanks!!!

Comment: Take a look here: https://www.kirupa.com/html5/accessing_your_webcam_in_html5.htm

Comment: it's entirely device specific as to whether clicking on a file input control triggers the camera, or the option to use the camera. And you can't tell the difference because the HTML page just has a file input control. If the device links this to the camera, all it does it take a picture, store it, and then put the path of this file into the file input control on the page, just as it would if it selected an older picture. The process, from the point of view of your site, is identical, whether the picture was taken 10 seconds ago or 10 years ago.

Comment: And who's to say the user _wants_ to send you a photo of them literally right now - maybe they're in their pyjamas or have mad-professor hair? If you accept "recent" photos, surely if it was taken a couple of days ago (or even a few weeks ago) makes no practical difference? What's your actual objection to this? Specify how recent the photo should be and make the user certify that it meets the requirement. There's really not much else you can do.

Comment: Oh, I understand. Right, but I've to search any way to control this. My objection to do this is that the web site it's for a company that requires that the photo be taken right now, for a matter of security and not fakeness.

Comment: Well you have to tell them their requirement is technically impossible to implement. And anyway even if it were possible, it still proves nothing - who's to say the person in the photo is really the person registering? Easy enough to take a photo of someone else who is nearby at the time.  And most phones have tools to let you manipulate the photo significantly after you take it. If they seriously care that much they need to ask for originals of verifiable ID documents by post, which they then return by recorded delivery. Really it's not even a code problem, it's just an illogical request.

Comment: You can of course go with Brainfeeder's suggestion below, and it superficially makes it look like the date was correct, but this can be changed by the user. It's also possible that the camera software simply didn't complete that field, or the device had the wrong time set. It provides no more real-life protection than any other solution. Online, pretty much everything is fake-able.

Comment: All you can do is ask the user to tick a box saying that the image is truthfully of them and was taken within whatever timescale you deem acceptable. Then make it part of the site's terms and conditions that if this is found to be untrue then it violates the usage agreement and they can be deleted (or whatever other punishment is appropriate). Make it a legal issue not a technological one. This is probably something you need to discuss with the people who commissioned you to build this site.

Comment: I understand that, but who said that the photo has to be from the face or body of the user? I only need a simple control that check the date of the image that is uploading, nothing else. The users of the web site will be a standar user, don't have technical knowledge, so I don't think that he can manipulate the metadata of the photo. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, I see you are using PHP server-side... If you don't mind uploading the image without checking first, you can build in a check server-side.

With `exif_read_data()` you can read metadata from an image. [See documentation for all details](http://php.net/manual/en/function.exif-read-data.php)

The `FileDateTime` will hold the date of when the image was created. Thus you could check if the image is a recent image.

Another possible way is to check which camera was used. It depends on which device was used to take the picture if these values are set.

```
$exif_ifd0 = exif_read_data($tempImagePath ,'IFD0' , 0);
// $exif_ifd0 will be an array.
```

The last method is illustrated in [this comment](http://php.net/manual/en/function.exif-read-data.php#107888) at php.net

Comment: Oh great! Thanks, I'll try this right now and I'll let you know!

Comment: I hope this does what you try to do.. please note that images are user input.. and you should never trust user input. The metadata can be edited on a computer.. So if it works, it is not tamper-proof.

Comment: I'm right now trying some things with this solution. Yeah of course, I undertand that isn't a  tamper-proof, but it works for what I need. Thks!

Comment: Glad I could help